# Steering wheel stiff while turning while driving

Tags: honda, steering, crv

Just bought a 2004 Honda CRV, and it runs great. The only thing is, I noticed a small tick sound coming from the steering wheel column. The sound didn't raise any red flags, but now the steering wheel starts to get really stiff as I drive and makes it hard to turn the wheel left or right. What might be going on?

Comment: In the future, JEN, please turn down the volume.

Comment: Do you hear anything like a whining noise when you turn the wheel? Are the front tire pressures correct? Do you hear any other noises while turning the wheel? How does the steering feel if you turn the wheel while standing still and engine at idle? How many miles on the vehicle? Which engine?

Answer (score 4):

My first thought would be the power steering system. On most modern cars there is a power steering pump, which is powered either by the engine mechanically (like with a belt) or electrically. This pumps power steering fluid to help assist with steering and make the steering wheel feel lighter in your hands. More info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_steering

I would recommend, at the very least, checking the power steering fluid level. There should be a reservoir under the hood. You can find instructions in your owners manual to help.